# unable to connect mysql with jsp page

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, connection

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<title>Contact</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Terminal_Dosis_300.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script> <style type="text/css"> .bg {behavior:url(js/PIE.htc)} </style> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <div style='clear:both;text-align:center;position:relative'> <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://www.theie6countdown.com/images/upgrade.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a> </div> <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page6">
    <div class="body1">
        <div class="body2">
            <div class="body3">
                <div class="main">
                    <!-- header -->
                    <header>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <h1>
                                <a href="index.jsp" id="logo"></a>
                            </h1>
                            <form id="search" method="post">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value=""> <input
                                        class="input" type="text" value="Site Search"
                                        onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Site Search'"
                                        onFocus="if(this.value =='Site Search' ) this.value=''">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <nav>
                                <ul id="menu">
                                    <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="About.jsp">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="folio.jsp">Folio</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="services.jsp">Services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="news.jsp">News</a></li>
                                    <li id="active" class="end"><a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="ic">More Website Templates at
                        TemplateMonster.com!</div>
                    <!-- / header-->
                    <!-- content -->
                    <section id="content">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <h2>Contact Form</h2>
                            <form id="ContactForm">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                        <span>Your Name:</span><input type="text" name="name"
                                            class="input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                        <span>Your E-mail:</span><input type="text" name="Eid"
                                            class="input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="textarea_box">
                                        <span>Your Message:</span>
                                        <textarea name="Query" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <span>&nbsp;</span> <a href="#" class="button"
                                        onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()">Clear</a>
                                    <a href="conus.jsp" class="button"
                                        onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">Send</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body4">
        <div class="main">
            <section id="content2">
                <div class="line2 wrapper">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <article class="col1">
                            <h2>Miscellaneous</h2>
                            <div class="pad">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus
                                error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam
                                rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et
                                quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
                                ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut
                                fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione
                                voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est.</div>
                        </article>
                        <article class="col2 pad_left1">
                            <h2>My Contacts</h2>
                            <div class="pad">
                                <span class="col3"> <strong> Country:<br>
                                        State:<br> City:<br> Telephone:<br> Email:
                                </strong>
                                </span> USA<br> California<br> San Diego<br> <br> <a
                                    href="mailto:">elenwhite@mail.com</a>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / content -->
    <div class="main">
        <!-- footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span class="left"> <a rel="nofollow" href=" target="_blank">Website
                        template</a> designed by <br>
                </span>
                <ul id="icons">
                    <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Facebook"><img
                            src="images/icon1.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Delicious"><img
                            src="images/icon2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Stumble Upon"><img
                            src="images/icon3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Twitter"><img
                            src="images/icon4.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Linkedin"><img
                            src="images/icon5.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Reddit"><img
                            src="images/icon6.png" alt=""></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
        </footer>
        <!-- / footer -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Cufon.now();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<%-- Document : conus Created on : Sep 5, 2013, 12:22:49 PM Author : Jai
--%> <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ page language="java" %> <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> <%@ page
    import="java.sql.DriverManager.*" %> <% String
    s=request.getParameter("name"); String s1=request.getParameter("Eid");
    String textarea=request.getParameter("Query"); PreparedStatement ps;
    Connection con; ResultSet rs= null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhos:3306/prior" +
    "user=root&password=root"); Statement st=con.createStatement(); ps=
    con.prepareStatement("insert into contact values (?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1,s); ps.setString(2, s1); ps.setString(3,textarea); int
    insertResult = ps.executeUpdate(); if (insertResult!=0) {
    out.println("WE WILL BE IN TOUCH SOON"); } %>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <% response.sendRedirect("contact.jsp");%>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```